# How can I force ticks to have a certain spacing and range using contourf() in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I'm creating a series of contours to be presented simultaneously; some plots have data in the range (0,6) and some are (4,6), but I'd like all contours to have the same colorbar which ranges from 0 to 6.

For the plots with data in the range (0,6), the colorbar has a range (0,6), but for the other plots in the range (4,6) the colorbar ticks are spaced strangely, making it appear that multiple colors correspond to the same value.  The plot has data binned into integer values.

[Plot with data in range (0,6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbfFr.png)

[Plot with data in range (4,6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlW29.png)

Here's what I've written to plot them, please let me know if additional information would be useful:

```
plt.contourf(r,mass2,D_stdev_coarse)
plt.title('Likely Binary Parameters for System with M={}, Plot 1'.format(m_tot))
plt.xlabel('R [km]')
plt.ylabel('M2, M1={}'.format(mass1))
plt.colorbar(ticks=[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0])
plt.show()
```

Thanks so much in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the levels for the contour plot. That way the corresponding colorbar takes these levels into account:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2, 2, 200), np.linspace(-2, 2, 200))
z1 = 3 + 1.5 * (np.sin(x) + np.cos(y*y))
z2 = 5 + 0.5 * (np.sin(x) + np.cos(y*y))

#cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['dodgerblue', 'crimson'], 2)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
contour1 = ax1.contourf(x, y, z1, levels=range(7), alpha=0.8)
plt.colorbar(contour1, ax=ax1)
contour2 = ax2.contourf(x, y, z2, levels=range(4, 7), alpha=0.8)
plt.colorbar(contour2, ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  I just tried this and it works perfectly.  Simply adding in levels=range(7) as an argument for contourf() solved my problem.  I appreciate it and hope you're well.  :)